# Calculate date/time difference form entries in two files in bash script

Tags: bash, rhel, timestamps

I have two files (STARTED and COMPLETED) that look like this:

STARTED FILE:

```
2018-01-30 10:21:41
2018-01-17 12:22:50
2018-06-27 23:09:20
INVALID
INVALID
... for 800 Rows
```

COMPLETED FILE:

```
2018-01-30 10:23:54
2018-01-17 13:23:45
2018-06-28 06:10:56
INVALID
INVALID
... for 800 rows
```

I need to create a third file that has the result of difference of each row for file2 and file1 - to get the time lapse.

NEW 3rd FILE:

```
00:02:13
01:00:55
07:01:36
INVALID     //Where any instance of invalid in either file remain in the new file.
INVALID
```

... for 800 rows

I was able to get this to work manual using this command but no luck looping through my file:

```
string1="10:21:41"
string2="10:23:54"
StartDate=$(date -u -d "$string1" +"%s")
FinalDate=$(date -u -d "$string2" +"%s")
date -u -d "0 $FinalDate sec - $StartDate sec" +"%H:%M:%S"

> 00:02:13
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH SouravGosh!  This worked PERFECTLY using base system utilities!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as oneliner

```
while read -r StartDate  && read -r FinalDate <&3; do if [[ ${StartDate} != "INVALID" && ${FinalDate} != "INVALID" ]]; then diff=$(expr $(date -d "${FinalDate}" +"%s") - $(date -d "${StartDate}" +"%s")); printf '%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $((${diff}/86400)) $((${diff}%86400/3600)) $((${diff}%3600/60)) $((${diff}%60));else echo INVALID; fi; done < startedfile 3<finishedfile
```

as a script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r StartDate  && read -r FinalDate <&3; do 
    if [[ ${StartDate} != "INVALID" && ${FinalDate} != "INVALID" ]]; then 
        diff=$(expr $(date -d "${FinalDate}" +"%s") - $(date -d "${StartDate}" +"%s")); 
        printf '%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $((${diff}/86400)) $((${diff}%86400/3600)) $((${diff}%3600/60)) $((${diff}%60));
    else 
        echo INVALID; 
    fi; 
done < startedfile 3<finishedfile
```

It will give output like this:

```
0d:0h:2m:13s
0d:1h:0m:55s
INVALID
0d:7h:1m:36s
INVALID
INVALID
```

you can then just output that to file you want.

---

EDIT

As suggested in the comments, this can be simplified by installing `dateutils` package and using `datediff` command.

```
while read -r StartDate  && read -r FinalDate <&3; do if [[ ${StartDate} != "INVALID" && ${FinalDate} != "INVALID" ]]; then datediff "${StartDate}" "${FinalDate}" -f "%dd:%Hh:%Mm:%Ss";else echo INVALID; fi; done < started.txt 3<finished.txt
```

In a script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r StartDate  && read -r FinalDate <&3; do 
    if [[ ${StartDate} != "INVALID" && ${FinalDate} != "INVALID" ]]; then 
        datediff "${StartDate}" "${FinalDate}" -f "%dd:%Hh:%Mm:%Ss";
    else 
        echo INVALID; 
    fi; 
done < startedfile 3<finishedfile
```

Comment: As simplification, I'd suggest using `ddiff` from the `dateutils` package which allows subtracting date strings directly: `dateutils.ddiff "$startdate" "$enddate" ` gives the difference in seconds or a format defined by e.g. `-f %H:%M:%S`, i.e. matching `date`'s formatting system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to solve your problem with the following bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sfile=/path/to/start
efile=/path/to/end
ofile=/path/to/out
n=0

while read -r line; do
    ((n++))
    if [[ $line == 'INVALID' ]]; then
        echo "INVALID"
        continue
    fi
    start=$(date -u -d "$line" "+%s")
    end=$(date -u -d "$(sed -n "${n}p" "$efile")" "+%s")
    date -u -d "0 $end sec - $start sec" +"%H:%M:%S"
done<"$sfile" >"$ofile"
```

This will read each line of the start file and compare it to the matching line in the end file.  If the line contains "INVALID" it will echo "INVALID" and skip to the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: With GNU `date` you can get it to read dates from a file with `-f`. This means that you could potentially get away with just one or two invocations of `date` instead of 800.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ddiff` from GNU `dateutils`, and `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

paste STARTED COMPLETED |
while IFS=$'\t' read start compl; do
    if [ "$start" = "INVALID" ] || [ "$compl" = "INVALID" ]; then
        echo 'INVALID'
    else
        ddiff -f '%0H:%0M:%0S' "$start" "$compl"
    fi
done
```

Assuming the input files are called `STARTED` and `COMPLETED`, this creates a tab-delimited input to the `while` loop with the start times in the first field and the completion times in the second field.  It reads these and checks whether any of the two times are `INVALID`.  If not, it calls `ddiff` with them.

The output of this could be saved to a file with a redirection after `done` at the end, or after the script name on the command line when invoking the script.

Running it on the supplied data:

```
$ bash script.sh
00:02:13
01:00:55
07:01:36
INVALID
INVALID
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
# usage: that-script file1 file2
zmodload zsh/datetime
while
  IFS= read -ru3 a &&
   IFS= read -ru4 b
do
  if
    strftime -rs at '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$a" 2> /dev/null &&
      strftime -rs bt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$b" 2> /dev/null
  then
    d=$((bt - at))
    printf '%02d:%02d:%02d\n' $((d/3600)) $(((d/60)%60)) $((d%60))
  else
     printf '%s\n' $a
  fi
done 3< ${1?} 4< ${2?}
```

That's still using a shell loop to process text [which is generally considered bad practice](/q/169716) but at least here we're only using builtin commands which means performance is not going to be as dreadful as if you were invoking two external GNU `date` commands for each line of input.